# Defining a threshold for percentage data with high amounts of exact zeros

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, poisson-distribution, biostatistics, zero-inflation

I am trying to analyse my biological data which is derived from flow cytometry and describes the percentage of cells with a certain property. Data is available for two conditions: once the cells areuntreated and once the cells were stimulated. For the untreated condition I analysed 57 samples, for the stimulated condition 39, which can be considered as more or less independent random variables. In both conditions, I have a lot of samples with exactly 0.0000% cells with the property of interest, however in the treated condition there are some samples that show "high" percentage (up to 0.35%). (exemplary data posted at the end of the post)

I now want to use the samples of the "untreated" condition to define a threshold for random background activation in order to say in the "treated" condition from which % on, I can treat the sample as "really" positive for the property. Initially, I tried to define the mean of the untreated condition, add 2 times the standard deviation (calculated on Poisson model) and set this as the threshold. However, it turned out that the standard deviation as defined by Poisson distribution is getting quite big when calculating with these small numbers. This led to the threshold cutting off a number of events I think should be real.

The problem is now, that I don't know which model I should apply to solve this problem. I tried transformations however, since the 0 values are exactly 0, I never got rid of them. Further, I read something about zero-inflated Poisson distributions but I don't know whether that helps here and I also don't really know how to apply that.

**So to summarize, the problem is: How can I say about a single event in the treated condition whether it is significantly higher than the mean of the untreated condition?**

If someone has some advice on how to deal with this data, I would be really grateful.

Thanks a lot.

Cheers,
Florian

**Data**

Treated: 0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0130,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0021,
0.0010,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0016,
0.0021,
0.0054,
0.0056,
0.0067,
0.0000,
0.0022,
0.0052,
0.0000,
0.0004,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0021,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0283,
0.0142,
0.0215,
0.3570,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0093,
0.0109,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0011,
0.0000

Untreated: 0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0021,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0043,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0039,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0020,
0.0010,
0.0015,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000,
0.0000

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is stimulated=treated and unstimulated=untreated? Don't you want to use both sets of data to define a threshold? Then you'll get some estimate of false positives/false negatives.

Comment: yep sorry for that. untreated = unstimulated and treated=stimulated. ideally I only want to use the untreated samples to define the threshold. so in the end I want to find the events in the treated fraction that are significantly different from the untreated condition. It is not about comparing both conditions as a whole because also in the treated conditions only few samples actually contain cells with the property I am interested in.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use a Vuong test to determine if your results are zero-inflated. If they are zero inflated, then there are a "high amount of zeros".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuong's_closeness_test